# Magento 2 can't get customer details in observer

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, customer

I am using observer for after customer save with following event `customer_save_after_data_object`

I am trying to get the customer id in observer with following script,

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
    //Do your stuff here!
    echo "<pre>";
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    print_r($customer);
    die('Observer Is called!');        
}
```

Here i can see die result but am't able to customer data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no object called customer, if we look into the CustomerRepository Model where the event is dispatched, passed data looks like this

```
$savedCustomer = $this->get($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_save_after_data_object',
        ['customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer, 'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer]
    );
return $savedCustomer;
```

So, instead of `$observer->getCustomer();` you will have to `$observer->getCustomerDataObject();`.

Also, you can try to do it with classic events like `customer_save_before` and `customer_save_after`, where you can do it your way, with `$observer->getCustomer();`